# How to remove particular Pantone(Spot Colors) or CMYK colors in PDF and save the resulting PDF file?

Tags: pdf, colors, pdf.js, cmyk, pdf-manipulation

I am developing an application where I have a PDF file that contains Multiple Pantone and CMYK colors(spot colors). I need to programmatically remove one or more specified spot colors and save the resultant PDF file. I'm open to approaches of any language and libraries. Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand. What it is a Pantone in a PDF? (the real advantage of Pantone is about real colours, so that same Pantone will behave the same on all type of external illumination). Maybe you should describe and example (no need to be programmatically) so we understand the input and what do you expect as output.

Comment: Indeed, what exactly do you mean by Pantone colors contained in a PDF? As spot colors? As base colors of some **DeviceN** color space, e.g. Pantone Hexachrome? Or something else?